# Сообщения об ошибках валидации в форме bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, валидация

Использую стандартную форму bootstrap, поля валидируются и выводится сообщение об ошибке. На данный момент реализованно так:

```
<% if @stock.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
  <%= pluralize(@stock.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this stock from being saved:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <% @stock.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= form_for :stock, url: stocks_path do |f| %>
....
<% end %>
```

Сообщения выходят но форма начинает разъезжаться, те поля которые не прошли валидацию обворачиваются тегом div с классом field_with_errors

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="stock-name">Name</label> 
</div>
```

Как это проправить, а лучше сообщения об ошибках валидации сделать как у [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation)

Понятно что можно навесит на класс field_with_errors стили бутстрапа, но я хочу наоборот классы бутстрапа использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле  `environments/development.rb` переопределить этот метод

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  html_tag
}
```

[Вот более полный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t)